# Android:VM crashed for background drawable

Tags: java, android

I make a style which assigns the background for the application and add the style in the `mainfest.xml`.

I made **two pictures** in `drawable-land` and `drawable-port` for the application's background drawable.When I test my app on the phone and **rotate** the phone some times, the app crashed for the app background drawable overflow.

SO how can I control this? Is there anyone can tell me how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the LogCat say anything?

Comment: Are you locking your device before rotating?? If yes then post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

if the exception/error that is shown in the logcat is outOfMemory (something like "java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget." ) , you need to handle the image in a more efficient way since it takes too much memory for the device/emulator to use.

i would recommend to either lower the quality , depending on the density of the device , and also read the [android bitmap handling tips](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)